# Maven copy built war file to sibling module

Tags: maven

I'm converting an ant project to maven.  I need to copy the war file that gets created to a sibling module.  How would I do this?

Edit:  My question isn't very clear, so I'm going to expand.  I have a multi-module project with 2 child modules: A and B.  Module A produces a war, and module B produces a jar.  I would like to copy the war produced by module A to the target directory of module B.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking about, please improve your question! Probably you want to use "overlay" from maven-war-plugin.

Comment: Does not make sense. For what purpose do you need the war file in the jar project ?

Comment: The reason is that eventually all the files in that directory are going to be packaged into an installer.

Comment: If you like to create an installer it's best having a separate module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the war as dependency which means something like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>theArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Or you can use the [maven-dependency-plugin to copy a dependency or an artifact:](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html)

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```